# SwiftUI unable to align button with topLeading

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `button` which I am unable to align to the top left with `topLeading`.
What I hope to accomplish:

[image: What I want]

my code:

```swift
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Button(action: { self.show.toggle() }) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
                    .frame(width: 90, height: 60)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                    .shadow(color: Color("buttonShadow"), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
                }
                Spacer()
            }

        }
    }
```

But I get this:

[image: My work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your wrapping views (two `ZStack`s) by default will take up only the space of their content, which is only the button. If you add a frame to allow the wrapper to expand you'll see the alignment working as you expect.

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: { self.show.toggle() }) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                .padding(.trailing, 20)
                .frame(width: 90, height: 60)
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .shadow(color: Color.gray, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            maxHeight: .infinity,
            alignment: Alignment.topLeading
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of correct behavior]

Answer (score 1):

Add background space consumer, like below (tested with Xcode 11.4)

[image: demo]

```
ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
    Color.clear                               // << here !!
    Button(action: { self.show.toggle() }) {
```

Comment: Wow, But what does it mean? On tutorial I don't see setting color?